# How to unwind subdocument array, and then reverse the process, without losing other keys?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I'm completely new to Mongoose.

I have this Schema:

```
const houseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  _id: String,
  housename:  {type: String,unique: true},
  adress: String,
  people: [ {
      name: String,
      age: Number
    } ],
});
```

And document:

```
 let house = new House({
    _id: 20,
    housename: "white",
    adress: "St1",
    people:[
      {name: "Jon", age: 23},
      {name: "Ann", age:50},
      {name: "Pat", age:20},
      {name: "Helen", age:15}]
  });
```

I want to find this document by id, and filter people array by age, then return full document without filtered objects. So expected output would be: (for age>21 ):

```
{
    _id: 20,
    housename: "white",
    adress: "St1",
    people:[
      {_id:"65976faeaa644d02c4090826", name: "Jon", age: 23},
      {_id:"65976faeaa644d02c4090827", name: "Ann", age:50}
    ]
 }
```

My solution to this problem, after hours of trying is:

```
app.get("/api/test", (req, res) => {
  var searchID = "20";
  var minAge = 21;
  House.aggregate([{$match: {_id: searchID}}])
  .unwind("people").match({'people.age': {$gt: minAge}})
  .group({    
        _id: "$_id",       
        people: {$push: "$people"}         
  }) 
  .exec((err,data)=>{
        res.json(data); 
    }); 
});
```

So first I match id, then rewind people array - so I can filter it out, and then I try to rejoin to the first form. **However after grouping I lose *housename* and *adress* fields.** Here is output:

```
{"_id":"20",
"people":[
{"_id":"65976faeaa644d02c4090826","name":"Jon","age":23},{"_id":"65976faeaa644d02c4090827","name":"Ann","age":50}]}
```

I have no idea how to keep *housename* and *adress* fields at the output. I've tried adding.projection({housename:1 ,adress:1 ... }); ,but it did nothing, I think those keys don't exist in pipe after group(). I also have been thinking about saving those values to vars after match() and then adding them at the end, but I don't know how to access them in the middle of the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `$filter` to filter the `people` objects that match your filter condition like so:

```js
app.get("/api/test", async (req, res) => { //< Mark as async
  var searchID = "20";
  var minAge = 21;
  try{
      const data = await House.aggregate([
      {
         $match: {
            "_id": searchID 
         }
      },
      {
         "$addFields": {
            people: {
               $filter: {
                  input: "$people",
                  as: "p",
                  cond: {
                     $gt: [
                        "$$p.age",
                        minAge 
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
      ]);
      res.json(data);
   } catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.json({message: 'Error on server'});
   }
});
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q_tBZuDJWE2) for a working example.

The use of [`$addFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) is important here because:

> Adds new fields to documents. `$addFields` outputs documents that contain all existing fields from the input documents and newly added fields. The
> `$addFields` stage is equivalent to a `$project` stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.

which I think was where you were having trouble with the `$project`. All I have done is use `$addFields` to overwrite the existing `people` property with the new filtered version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and also amazing site to test queries! However I have still very weak idea on how it works. From the description of $addField I read that it adds new record to existing one. So I would expect that anything, which is inside $addField {} brackets would be added/appended to the existing record - so the output record would have 4+2 elements in array "people". But it was replaced instead.

Comment: Also why condition looks like array:   $gt: ["$$p.age",21] and can't be formatted this way:? "$$p.age": { $gt: 22 }

Comment: The `$filter` is essentially the JavaScript `Array.prototype.filter()` which takes your  `people` array and makes a shallow copy of array elements that meet your conditions as the return value of the function. This new array is what `$addFields` uses to assign to the value of `people`. Since you already had a `people` property it's just overwritten. If you change `people` to `filteredPeople` in the `$addFields` stage you will see both array in the output. The `$gt` part is necessary for [expressions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#expression-operators).